# Como criar formulário dinamicamente em Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Bom estou tendo problemas ao criar a `form` no Delphi, estou usando um procedimento mas ele esta dando erro direto.

Alguem poderia me dizer um modo mais eficiente de criar uma `form` em Delphi?

Código atual:

```
procedure TLogin.CriarForm(NomeForm: TFormClass);
begin
  //Procedimento para criar formulario na memória
  with NomeForm do begin
    Try begin 
      TForm(NomeForm):=NomeForm.Create(Application); 
      TForm(NomeForm).Showmodal;
    end;

    Finally
      FreeAndNil(NomeForm);
    End; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: vixi man o delphi xe5 n fala so aponta pro parametro qnd chama a funcao tipo CriarForm(frmPrincipal); ate com aspas da erro

Comment: Pelo teu código, você tem que informar a classe do formulário, por exemplo: `CriarForm(TfrmPrincipal)` repare o `T` no começo.

Comment: blz vou tentar agr isso

Comment: msm erro dnv...

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou... Sem saber qual o erro aparece é difícil ajudar. :/

Comment: deixa eu ver se aparece alguma coisa aqui em baixo nas solucoes de erro

Comment: undeclared identifier parece que tem q declarar o form em algum lugar

Comment: Em `Uses` você colocou a *unit* do formulário?

Comment: coloquei um uses la em cima do modulo de dados a frmPrincipal n puis pa criar automaticamente qnd compila pra criar dinamicamente depois

Comment: coloquei no uses agr e deu msm erro

Comment: ae agr foi tava faltando um ponto

Comment: CriarForm(frmSistema.TPrincipal);

Comment: blz vlw vou da uma olhada la

Comment: Gabriel, se possível [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/152604/edit) a pergunta e coloque o erro que era apresentado! Se preferir poste uma resposta com a resolução do erro. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro no seu código está em:

```
procedure TLogin.CriarForm(NomeForm: TFormClass);
begin
  //Procedimento para criar formulario na memória
  with NomeForm do begin
    Try begin //<- Não se abre um bloco begin-end dentro de blocos try-finally
      TForm(NomeForm):=NomeForm.Create(Application); 
      TForm(NomeForm).Showmodal;
    end; 

    Finally
      FreeAndNil(NomeForm);
    End; 
  end;
end;
```

A forma correta seria:

```
procedure TLogin.CriarForm(NomeForm: TFormClass);
begin
  //Procedimento para criar formulario na memória
  with NomeForm do 
  begin
    Try
      TForm(NomeForm):=NomeForm.Create(Application); 
      TForm(NomeForm).Showmodal;
    Finally
      FreeAndNil(NomeForm);
    End; 
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se "TFormClass" for uma referência de classe, o código pode ser assim:

```
procedure TLogin.CriarForm(NomeForm: TFormClass);
var
  form: TForm;
begin
  form := NomeForm.Create(Application);
  try
    form.ShowModal; 
  finally
    form.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Neste caso, NomeForm seria uma referência à classe de TForm ou descendente a ser criada. P.ex.: 

`type 
  TFormClass = class of TForm;
  ...`

CriarForm(TForm1);  //cria e exibe uma instância de TForm1
  CriarForm(TForm2);  //cria e exibe uma instância de TForm2 
  ...

Comment: Procure explicar o que você está fazendo no código para que essa resposta seja mais tangível a usuários futuros e ao dono da pergunta.